# SonarQube: Timeline and Branches

Tags: git, sonarqube

This question is more processlike than technical.

**SITUATION**

I use SonarQube to analyze my Code Quality and Git to version my code.

My "develop" branch is build and SonarQube analyzed every night (as far as something was changed).

On develop branch I use "SNAPSHOT" Versions (e.g. 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT)

When a release is ready for production I create a release Branch, set the Version on the release Branch to a fixed version (e.g. 1.1.0) and increment the Version on the develop branch to the next "SNAPSHOT" Version (with the previous examples it will be now 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT)

As far as my release branch is allowed to be modified (until it's final and will be merged to master) I also want to be informed about the quality of this branch.

Every time I modify the release branch the version will also get an autoincremented build-nr (so the final version-nr will be e.g. 1.1.0.001)

**PROBLEM**

I currently have 1 Project within SonarQube. This leads to gaps and jumps within my SonarQube Timeline when building from different branches.

E.g.:

1. 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
2. 1.1.0.001
3. 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
4. 1.1.0.002
5. 1.1.0.003
6. 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
7. ...

The Main Problem is not only the version-jumps but also the different issues (e.g. a bunch of issues got fixed on develop after the release branch was taken).

**QUESTION**

So my question is: What will be the best solution for this Problem?

- Skip Analysis on Release Branch?
- Create own "Release" Project on SonarQube for the analysis?
- Any other solutions?

Comment: we do have branch based analyses so, in our project every branch gets analysed -> this leads to 2 longliving analyses, some release branches, which do live shortly and really short feature branches. In my opinion you do not want to merge different branches, with different code status into one sonar project -> you will lose overview, and your historical data will be more likely useless, as you can not really tell if something happened due to a code change, or due to a different branch!

Answer (score 1):

depends what you are aiming for ->

- do you just do an analysis to know issues, or do you actively want people to work on sonar issues and stop them from creating one?

  than you should think of implementing some kind of tool, which is showing sonar issues in pull requests and try to elaborate the usage of SonarLint during the development process
- Do you just want to have historical data, how the code base evolved?

  than one branch is enough, and i would recommend the production branch
- Do you want to see really changes over time, and want to prevent too many "new issues" but full feature branch is too much?

  than i would suggest to simply run the analyses for the develop, production and release branches

In our company, new projects are nearly always analysed on feature branch, nobody will fix sonar issues afterwards, this is just creating a lot of overhead. We do have some projects with quite old sourcecode, but even their we try to use feature branch analysis to improve the code base.

This is really a project specific and goal specific topic

Comment: We use sonarlint for the feature branches to give the developers the possibility to check the source before commit. But I also need to have an overview (and the development) of the overall quality (so an analysis of the develop branch). To prevent a quality loss of the release branch this should also be checked. 
I guess the best way is to have 2 different sonar projects. One for the develop branch (timeline) and one for the release branches (current situation).

Comment: i forgot to mention with sonar 6.7 there will be a commercial feature which supports branch on projects!

Comment: sonarlint is nice, but does not cover custom sonar plugins like findbugs, pmd, checkstyle, etc. so you can just cover plugins which are maintained by Sonar themselves - so sonarlint works if you do not use additional plugins

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Branch+Plugin -> at least the docs of the new plugin is live also the new LTS is live!

Comment: OK. thx. Will give the Plugin a try. Meanwhile I have created 2 different Projects. Project 1 will be filled with "develop" branch analysis (will always go forward, never backward). Project 2 will be used for moment analysis (timeline is irrelevant as the versions can jump forward and backward).